# Error: The app has not been configured with a WORKSPACE_ID environment variable

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson, watson, watson-conversation

I've changed the workspace ID in both my env file as well as my app.js file just in case. I've installed all the necessary SDK's and have done everything according to the instructions [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple?cm_mc_uid=30583787099214821722366&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1482287206).

I swapped out the workspace files with my own workspace. But I made all the necessary changes including changing the workspace ID. Not quite sure why i'm still getting the error. Any help would be much appreciated!

Edited: Here are the changes I made to my code

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAUmA.png)

Comment: can u paste the nodejs code here

Comment: Hey @ShekharTyagi I just posted a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem a few days ago. And, to solved this, you can paste the `WORKSPACE_ID` in this [line](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/blob/master/app.js#L42) **too**!

But, if you want use the `.env` file, make sure the are no `spaces` between `=` and the end of the `line`.

I will put the print of my `app.js` as an example to help you:

[image]

Actually, both ways **work**.

My example show this:

```
  username = "<iwdiaowd-jioawjd-ioajgr-ogxgxajofa>" 
  password = "<xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>"  

  var workspace = "<59583409583495834590385394>"`
```

Try edit your .env:

```
WLP_SKIP_MAXPERMSIZE=true
VCAP_SERVICES={"conversation": [{"name": "conversation-service","label": "conversation","plan": "free","credentials": {"url": "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api","isStreaming": false,"password": "-ReplaceMe-","username": "-ReplaceMe-"}}]}
COLLECTION_NAME=workspace
WORKSPACE_ID=iwdiaowd-jioawjd-ioajgr-ogxgxajofa
LOGGING_ENABLED=false
```

Comment: Hi Sayuri, I've tried that! But it still unfortunately doesn't work. I even changed the workspace ID where it says workspace ===. But it still doesn't work. Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: If you look at the edit picture I put up, that's how i placed my information in the app.js file. In the .env file, I made the changes as mentioned (replaced the -replaceme- bit with my information, but I'm still getting the same error. I'm assuming the "conversation-service" bit is the app name and not the service name? Again, thanks for helping me figure this out. Did I miss something?]

Comment: If the "conversation-service" bit is infact the service name, I've tried that too, and it still doesn't work. Not quite sure where I'm going wrong! :/

Comment: if you want, i will send my archive (.env) example for your, just pass mail

Comment: and yes, the "conversation-service" in the case is the name of service, example, If you create a new service, you can put whatever name you want. If you put "conversation", edit the name in the .env file

Comment: That would be perfect! It's pranav.menon@live.com Thanks again Sayuri! :)

Comment: I sent the .env and the app.js to help you. :)